# Find the Potential Solution of the Initial Value Problem where constants $a >0, b>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The IVP is as follows: $xy'=y-b \sqrt {x^2+y^2},$ for all $x>0$

$y(a) = 0$

My Work: $xy'=y-b\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$y' =\frac yx -b \sqrt{\cfrac {x^2+y^2}{x^2}}$

$y' = \frac yx-b\sqrt{1 + \cfrac {y^2}{x^2}}$

This is a homogeneous equation is so let $v = \frac yx $ so $y=vx$ and $y'=v+v'x$

subbing in these values into the DE we get

$v + v'x = v - b \sqrt {1 + v^2}$

$v'x = -b\sqrt{1 + v^2}$

let's set x as the dependent variable and v as the independent variable.

$\cfrac {dx}{dv\cdot x} = \cfrac{1}{-b\sqrt{1+v^2}}$

$\cfrac{dv}{-b\sqrt{1+v^2}} = \cfrac {dx}{x}$

$\int \cfrac{dv}{-b\sqrt{1+v^2}} =\int  \cfrac {dx}{x}$

$\cfrac {-1}{b}ln|\sqrt{v^2+1}+v| = ln|x|+C_1$

take both sides as exponents of e to get

$\cfrac {1}{(\sqrt{v^2+1}+v)^{1/b}} = C_1x$

$x = \cfrac{1}{C_1(\sqrt {v^2+1} + v)^{1/b}}$

$\cfrac {1}{C_1} $ can just be written as another constant ${C_2}$ right?

So the General Solution can be simplified down to

$\cfrac{C_2}{(\sqrt{v^2+1}+v)^{1/b}}=x$ correct?

Now I really need help with this next part.

The solution says using the Initial Condition $y(a) = 0$,

We have $a = C$

HOW? How do we have $a = C$, i'm not seeing it. Can someone show me the algebra?

Also can tell me if i have the right idea with constants above?

Thank You

Comment: Deom $\cfrac{C_2}{(\sqrt{v^2+1}+v)^{1/b}}=x$ You have $v=0/a=0$ then $C_2=a$ for $a \ne 0$

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank You! Just a quick question. I have the right idea with constants with 1/C1 = C2 correct?

Comment: You're welvome Sleeper. Yes you can rewrite the constant like that.

Comment: I would rather transform to $v+\sqrt{1+v^2}=Cx^{-b}$, where the constant is closer to the independent variable. After squaring $1=C^2x^{-2b}-2vCx^{-b}$ or $v=\frac12(Cx^{-b}-C^{-1}x^b)$.